# Python: Compute the area and perimeter of structures from arrays of ones and zeros

Tags: python, arrays, opencv, shapes, contour

I am facing the following issue: I have two 2D-arrays of ones and zeros (same shape; (1920,1440)), which specify the masks and outlines of objects. Here, ones indicate space occupied by said objects and zeros indicate empty space (ones indicate the outlines and zeros indicate empty space respectively).

Here you can find a graphical representation of the mask array: https://ibb.co/v36TrJv and here you can find a graphical representation of the outlines array: https://ibb.co/FxKwmTq. Ones are depicted in white and zeros are depicted in black.

As you can see, the masks form ellipse-like structures, which do not overlap and the outlines always form closed contours. I now would like to compute the area occupied by each structure as well as the perimeter. Ideally, I would end up with two 2D-arrays with the same shape as the input arrays. Here, the first array would hold the area of each structure at the points where the mask array has a value of one. Analogously, the second array would hold the respective perimeter of each structure at these points. I need the output arrays to be in this form, so that I can do shape index computations and produce graphical representations of the results.

As a minimum reproducible example you can download the images from provided links and use the following code to extract the arrays from them:

```
import skimage.io as sio
import numpy as np

masks = sio.imread("masks.png")
masks = np.mean(masks, axis =2)/255

outlines = sio.imread("outlines.png")
outlines = np.mean(outlines, axis=2)/255
```

I have already played around a bit with OpenCV, as it apparently has functions, which are specifically designed for the applications I am looking for. Yet, my efforts have not yielded any notable results so far. I tried to adapt the example code from the contour features section of the OpenCV Docs (https://docs.opencv.org/trunk/dd/d49/tutorial_py_contour_features.html):

```
import cv2 as cv
img = cv.imread('masks.png',0)
ret,thresh = cv.threshold(img,127,255,0)
contours,hierarchy = cv.findContours(thresh, 1, 2)
cnt = contours[0]
print(cnt)
```

Here, the outcome does not seem to be what I am looking for. I also tried to adjust the threshold but without success. I am unable to figure out which adjustments I would have to make in order to arrive at my desired results using OpenCV.

Furthermore, I have come across Green's theorem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_theorem) and was considering to give implementing it for my purpose a try. But I thought I first ask for some external help, because I feel like there should be a more straight forward solution for my problem. Any help will be highly appreciated!

Comment: Just a general question here, what separation algorithm are you using and what is your initial input image.?

Comment: @RahulKedia I am doing automated segmentations of phase-contrast images of cell layers using _Cellpose_ (https://cellpose.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenCV's contours will do your work. I think you are understanding them wrong. In your code, contours[0] will only give the first contour detected. Whereas, you should iterate over the contours variable like `for contour in contours:`, and then for each contour, get the area and perimeter using the functions given in the doc you shared and store these details in a list of list. Thus your final list will be of size n×2 where n is the number of objects in your image.

Also, a suggestion there, find the contours in the image having the objects filled with ones and background with 0 as in the first image you shared. Also, just to be on safe side, as all your objects are separated, use RETR_EXTERNAL as a flag while finding the contours. Refer to OpenCV docs to get more information on this.

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick response! You have already helped me a lot! Do you have any idea how to reshape my results into the desired format?

Comment: What do you mean by reshape here.? Like what's the output.?

Comment: So, aside other representations, one of my main goals is to have an image just like the first one I shared, but with color-coding indicating the ratio P/sqrt(A) for every cell in the image, where P is the perimeter and A is the area. In the second paragraph of my initial question, I elaborated a possible output, which would allow for such an image. Do you have any suggestions how to arrive there? Again, I very much appreciate your help!

Comment: If I got your problem statement right here, to get the colour coded image,  first find the perimeter and area of the contours as discussed above and then first create a new blank image using `Image = np.zeros(initial_image.shape, dtype=np.uint8)`.  Now draw the found contours on this image using `cv2.drawContours(Image, [Contour], -1, Color, -1)` where `Contour` is the single contour found, and `Color` is the corresponding colour of that contour. (Draw contours using a for loop and in each iteration, draw a single contour in the image as shown.)

Comment: This was the perfect solution for my problem! Thank you very much for your kind help!